# A Single, Portable ZIP file to replace Android Studio

Tags: gratis, android, mobile, portable

Is there a single ZIP file (software inside the ZIP file) that android developer can download, and is portable (meaning you run from flash drive or portable hard disk), and can develop/build android apps without the need to connect to Internet? (Because the current Android studio requires too much time & resources, e.g. need to connect to the Internet to download separate files, such as gradle, and sometime require developer to find all the necessary files for setup in order to work smoothly)?

Example: An android developer download a ZIP file. The developer extract the content into a folder in his flash drive / portable hard disk. The developer click the "run.exe" file and start develop/build android apps. The software does not need to connect to the Internet. The developer save all his work in the flash drive / portable hard disk. The developer go home and plug into his computer and click the "run.exe" file to continue his work.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio has a zipped version but it is not portable by default.

I recently made a self-answered post at stackoverflow.com on how to make it portable by hand with few console tricks to use. The post has a room for further improvements but should be enough to start if not satisfies fully. Give comments if you use the way I described and find problems.

[Making Android Portable 2017+ versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65416525/making-android-studio-portable-2017-versions)

Java paths are in studio folder if no other version is set to be used. I will add setting a java folder into the post, but don't know when.